# Create a Command-based (i.e. console) application to read from Text file C#

Tags: c#, console

the application ask for user name and password. The application matches the login name and password from the already saved login names and their password given in a text file called “login.txt”. If the user name and password are correct then the application { do something ....}

I don't want to use contain, If I wrote in the textfile in this format, username:password, how can replace that instead of contain ???

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("E:\\login.txt"))
               {
                   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\login.txt");

                   {

                       if (lines.Contains(Username) && lines.Contains(Password))
                       {
                          .......
                       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.Split`

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("E:\\login.txt"))
   {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\login.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] userPassword = line.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (userPassword[0] == Username && userPassword[1] == Password)
            {
                //.....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split function which returns an array of string, first one will be user name and second is password.
Line.split(':');